# Exclude item using Where and item reference not always working

Tags: c#, linq

I had a bug in my code that was caused by these lines:

```
var itemToExclude = _myList.First();
var nextList = _myList.Where(i => i != itemToExclude);
```

where `itemToExclude` was still present in `nextList`.
I solved it by using `Skip(1)` instead of the second line, but what could cause the original code not to work?

The function used `yield return` which might have something to do with it.

`itemsToExclude` is a class with readonly properties similar to

```
class RemainingItems
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<MyObject> _myObjects;
    public IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObjects { get { return _myObjects; } }

    private readonly int _remaining;
    public int Remaining { get { return _remaining; } }

    public RemainingItems(IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects, int remaining)
    {
        _myObjects = myObjects;
        _remaining = remaining;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I don't know specifically, you may have to override the Equals operator in order to compare the two entities in the where clause successfully, though I have not had to do that when matching list elements (complex or not).

Comment: What is the type of itemToExclude?

Comment: Perhaps an `Equals` method that fails to support *reflexivity*?

Comment: can you give a list of sample data for which this fails to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `myList` is supplied by a yield-method it will recreate the items every time you iterate over the list. If you don't pay attention, it will create new objects on every iteration:

1. The first iteration will be started by `_myList.First()`
2. The second iteration will be started by `_myList.Where(...)`

You then compare objects with `!=` for inequality, which only evaluates to `false` when both references point to the same object (disregarding the actual contents of the objects). As described above, the yield-method probably creates new objects on every iteration, so `!=` will always be true.

There are several potential solutions:

- Using `.Skip(1)`
- Using `.ToArray()` on the list, so that the list will only be created once.
- Using a properly implemented `.Equals()` method

Each solution has its tradeoffs.

Comment: The objects for a `yield` are not recreated... Mind that yield returns references.

Comment: Yes, and often people write code like `yield return new Thingy() { ... }`. Which means that you'll get new/different objects every iteration.

Comment: true, but I'm quite confident that both `.Where` and `.Skip` don't create new objects...

Comment: `_myList.First()` will start a new iteration, and `_myList.Where(...)` will start a *second* iteration.

Comment: ah, I'm getting the level of `yield` you are talking about. Yes, that's correct.